# Libgdx - font are cut off at sites

Tags: android, libgdx

Well I can't get perfect fonts, or at least normal looking fonts to work. I'm using TTF and a viewport just for fonts (1440x2560). So at runtime I load up 4x size from 50-200 (which makes my loading times 3x longer).

Filters are Linear, Linear, since enabling MipMapping makes the fonts have a white border around (also no idea why).

Current fonts are cut of at bottom and the letters have different thickness.

Do I maybe have to use ScreenViewport? Since then it will load the exact sizes I guess, although then scaling screenViewport with the extendViewport seems like a big hassle.

Or what is happening?

UPDATE: Fixed it with: setUseIntegerPositions(false), it fixed every possible issue. From the border outline and the character's thickness...

Comment: Scaling an image down without mipmapping makes it look like you described. Not sure what the white border is that you're describing without seeing a picture. How are you generating your BitmapFont?

Comment: I use a Free Type Font generator. And load it into asset manager. And the moment I set in MipMapLinear, Linear I get a white border around SOME letters on the right and the top.    P.S I use normal Arial!

Comment: If the letters get scaled down by a large amount, pieces of adjacent letters will be interpolated across to other letters. You need to increase padding in the generator options to account for how much the size might be scaled down.

Comment: Umm, so I have to create a new .ttf with a generator? Like hiero (never used it)? You got to me first, but...: http://imgur.com/2tHpNd7 <--- this is the picture...

Comment: Not a new TTF. You said you use FreeTypeFontGenerator. Look at its options for padding the letters.

Comment: Where are it's options? I can't open the TTF.

Comment: The options for generating a font. You set the options by passing a FreeTypeFontParameter object to FreeTypeFontGenerator. To use custom padding, you have to use the `pixmapPacker` option to explicitly specify a PixmapPacker that has padding.

Comment: But really the whole reason to use FreeTypeFontGenerator is to generate a pixel perfect font that will not be scaled. (Otherwise you would create your font with something like Heiro and include it in your assets.) If you are supporting a wide range of screen dimensions, I would suggest generating your font at the exact pixel size it will be in screen, and then use a ScreenViewport or for other types of viewport scale the font to a size it will need to be to be sized pixel perfect on screen. (Camera height / screen height)

Comment: Using an extendViewport(1440x2560), I generate font size depending on % of Gdx.graphis.getHeight() and then scale it using (2560 / Gdx,graphics.getHeight(). Now they should be pixel perfect... But they look UGLIER than before. Although logicly they should look better! Even funnier it is, that if I use MipMapLinear filter I can still see the WHITE OUTLINE. (although very rarely and you have to look very carefully to see it, but it's there)

Comment: You should use the actual camera height, not the constant, because you can't be sure which way the ExtendViewport is going to modify the size. And you mixed width and height there, so the scale would be wrong anyway. And it needs to use nearest filtering with no mip-mapping to avoid blurriness.

Comment: Umm Gdx.graphics.getHeight() is y, so it's 2560, and should be correct. Also using Nearest, Nearest the characters are totally weird, ugly, like they aren't even readable.

Comment: Oops, but you should be using the camera height, not the constant. If you do use a constant, make sure you're using a float, not int. How about opening a thread at the Libgdx forums? Then you can post images and more code I can explain better.

Comment: Gonna post on libgdx with as much as I can.

Comment: You might want to look into distance field fonts https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts